# javascript - regex for alphanumeric and special character

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to build regex for string (company/organisation name) with below conditions:

- no leading or trailing space
- no double space in between
- shouldn't allow only single character (alphanumeric or white listed)
- can start with alphanumeric or white listed character
- shouldn't allow any white listed character entered multiple times

regex for these: `/(?! )([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-#&])+([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-#&\s])*(?<! )$/`

```js
console.log(/(?! )([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-#&])+([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-#&\s])*(?<! )$/.test('_')); // shouldn't allow

console.log(/(?! )([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-#&])+([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-#&\s])*(?<! )$/.test('a')); // shouldn't allow

console.log(/(?! )([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-#&])+([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-#&\s])*(?<! )$/.test('abc   abc')); // shouldn't allow

console.log(/(?! )([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-#&])+([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-#&\s])*(?<! )$/.test('_123')); // works fine

console.log(/(?! )([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-#&])+([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-#&\s])*(?<! )$/.test('# abc')); // works fine

console.log(/(?! )([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-#&])+([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-#&\s])*(?<! )$/.test('abc abc!')); // works fine

console.log(/(?! )([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-#&])+([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-#&\s])*(?<! )$/.test('abc abc# abc')); // works fine
```

current regex doesn't match all the criteria and couldn't figure out what's the problem with regex ?

Comment: Try `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.#&-]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9_.#&-]+)*$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this regex allows single character. `/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.#&-]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9_.#&-]+)*$/.test('#')` this should return false but it returns true.

Comment: @Valay what's a *"white listed character"?*

Comment: @zer00ne white listed characters _\.\-#&

Comment: sometimes I wonder why it all has to be done in one check. :)

Comment: I see your expected match also has `!`, but your regex does not have it. I added `!` to the character class in my answer. You may add more chars there, but mind `-` must stay at the end of the character class, right before `]`.

Comment: Is `####` (ten thousand times) a valid company name? If the answer is no, you might want to refine your requirements.

Comment: @georg valid point. that shouldn't be allowed. updating requirements. thanks.

Comment: What does `shouldn't allow more than one white listed character` mean? Punctuation?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my mistake. shouldn't allow any white listed character entered multiple times. updating.

Comment: If you want to say `_.#&!-` should only appear once in the string, add `(?!(?:[^_.#&!-]*[_.#&!-]){2})` after `^(?=.{2})`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?=.{2})(?!(?:[^_.#&!-]*[_.#&!-]){2})[a-zA-Z0-9_.#&!-]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9_.#&!-]+)*$/
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{2})` - any 2 chars must be at the start
- `(?!(?:[^_.#&!-]*[_.#&!-]){2})` - no 2 occurrences of `_.#&!-` chars in the string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_.#&-]+` - 1 or more allowed chars (other than whitespace)
- `(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9_.#&!-]+)*` - 0+ occurrences of

  - `\s` - 1 whitespace
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9_.#&!-]+` - 1+ letters, digits and some symbols
- `$` - end of string.

JS demo

```js
var rx = /^(?=.{2})(?!(?:[^_.#&!-]*[_.#&!-]){2})[a-zA-Z0-9_.#&!-]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z0-9_.#&!-]+)*$/;
console.log(rx.test('_')); // shouldn't allow
console.log(rx.test('a')); // shouldn't allow
console.log(rx.test('abc   abc')); // shouldn't allow
console.log(rx.test('_123')); // works fine
console.log(rx.test('# abc')); // works fine
console.log(rx.test('abc abc!')); // works fine
console.log(rx.test('abc abc# abc')); // works fine
```

Comment: your answer works perfectly but I added one more point in the requirements after georg pointed out.